# in windows-mobile, where to write exceptions?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

in windows-mobile, when i catch any exception - where to write it ?

in system ?  or any system log ?

and how to do it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: could you explain your question? Exception occur in run time?

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows Phone 7: You can write them to a log file in the Isolated Storage. That may require you to enable viewing the log file from within your application.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a per-hour, or per-any-time-interval log file in the root of running application, because Windows Mobile doesn't have an event log like Windows "desktop".

It would be easier to manage these logs if you store them in that place, because maybe you want to send them to some server over the network.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) for any non-trivial application. It's solid and configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can create your own log file at the location were  you have your exe of the application,Log file can be a per day log or weekly log it can be a text file...............